# Simple NAPI wrapper around self written C++ msgpack, horrible performance

Tags: c++, c++11, node.js, c++17, c++14

I have written a relatively small [msgpack](https://msgpack.org/index.html) implementation in C++, with performance that is not too bad, so I decided to write a NAPI wrapper around it, but the performance is just horrible. I am guessing this is because I'm having to find the type of everything before being able to pack it, and the performance of `Napi::Array` and `Napi::Object`.

```cpp
#include <napi.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "msgpack.hpp"

namespace node_msgpack {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace Napi;

    bool is_int(Env& env, Value& num) {
        return env.Global().Get("Number").ToObject().Get("isInteger").As<Function>().Call({ num }).ToBoolean().Value();
    }

    void pack(Env& env, vector<Value>& src, msgpack_byte::container& dest, bool initial = true);

    void pack(Env& env, Value& src, msgpack_byte::container& dest, bool initial = false) {
        switch (src.Type()) {
            case napi_boolean: {
                msgpack::pack(src.ToBoolean().Value(), dest);
                break;
            }
            case napi_number: {
                if (is_int(env, src)) {
                    int64_t num = src.ToNumber().Int64Value();
                    if (num >= 0) {
                        msgpack::pack_uint(num, dest);
                    }
                    else {
                        msgpack::pack_int(num, dest);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    msgpack::pack(src.ToNumber().DoubleValue(), dest);
                }
                break;
            }
            case napi_string: {
                msgpack::pack(src.ToString().Utf8Value(), dest);
                break;
            }
            case napi_null:
            case napi_undefined: {
                msgpack::pack(nullptr, dest);
                break;
            }
            case napi_object: {
                if (src.IsArray()) {
                    Array input_js_arr = src.As<Array>();
                    const uint32_t n = input_js_arr.Length();
                    vector<Value> input_vec;
                    input_vec.resize(n);
                    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        input_vec[i] = (input_js_arr.Get(i));
                    }
                    pack(env, input_vec, dest);
                }
                else {
                    Object input_js_obj = src.As<Object>();
                    Array obj_props = input_js_obj.GetPropertyNames();
                    const uint32_t n = obj_props.Length();
                    if (initial) {
                        dest.check_resize(size_t(msgpack::LengthOf(src) * compression_percent));
                    }
                    if (n <= 15) {
                        dest.push_back(fixmap_t(n));
                    }
                    else if (n <= umax16) {
                        dest.push_back(uint8_t(map16));
                        dest.push_back(uint16_t(n));
                    }
                    else if (n <= umax32) {
                        dest.push_back(uint8_t(map32));
                        dest.push_back(uint32_t(n));
                    }
                    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        Value key = obj_props.Get(i);
                        Value val = input_js_obj.Get(key);
                        pack(env, key, dest, false);
                        pack(env, val, dest, false);
                    }
                    if (initial) {
                        dest.shrink_to_fit();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void pack(Env& env, vector<Value>& src, msgpack_byte::container& dest, bool initial) {
        size_t n = src.size();
        if (initial) {
            dest.check_resize(size_t(msgpack::LengthOf(src) * compression_percent));
        }
        if (n <= 15) {
            dest.push_back(fixarray_t(n));
        }
        else if (n <= umax16) {
            dest.push_back(uint8_t(arr16));
            dest.push_back(uint16_t(n));
        }
        else if (n <= umax32) {
            dest.push_back(uint8_t(arr32));
            dest.push_back(uint32_t(n));
        }
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            pack(env, src[i], dest, false);
        }
        if (initial) {
            dest.shrink_to_fit();
        }
    }

    String stringify(const CallbackInfo& info) {
        Env env = info.Env();
        msgpack_byte::container dest;
        if (info.Length() == 0) {
            Error::New(env, "Expected an argument").ThrowAsJavaScriptException();
            return String::New(env, "");
        }
        Value input = info[0];
        pack(env, input, dest, true);
        return String::New(env, msgpack_byte::to_string(dest));
    }
}

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
    exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "stringify"), Napi::Function::New(env, node_msgpack::stringify));
    return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

The `msgpack::pack`, `msgpack::pack_uint` and `msgpack::pack_int` calls the `pack` function to the plain C++ msgpack library I wrote https://github.com/t348575/msgpack

Am I using the most efficient method to check types? I tried using visual benchmarking like shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlAH4dbMVnU), but I could not get anything useful out of it. To compare, the napi wrapper takes around 20 seconds to stringify ~400MB of data whereas the plain C++ takes only 0.4s to do the same. The entire code can be found [here](https://github.com/t348575/node-msgpack)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Profiling:

We could use a library like [Tracy](https://github.com/wolfpld/tracy) to do the sort of profiling you mention in the question. But it's quicker to ask "what's taking the most time" and get an answer with a profiler like [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy/), or the built in Visual Studio profiler.

So... I stuck your code into a project created with [create-vs-napi](https://github.com/billti/create-vs-napi), and ran stringify on some json data (~2MB) I had lying around. Obviously this kind of testing depends a lot on the actual data (I'm testing a scene graph type structure, with a fair mix of objects, arrays, strings and numbers).

First off, let's add an overall timer to check how long the code is taking:

```
String stringify(const CallbackInfo& info) {

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    Env env = info.Env();
    msgpack_byte::container dest;
    if (info.Length() == 0) {
        Error::New(env, "Expected an argument").ThrowAsJavaScriptException();
        return String::New(env, "");
    }
    Value input = info[0];
    pack(env, input, dest, true);
    String result = String::New(env, msgpack_byte::to_string(dest));

    auto duration = start - std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration).count();

    std::cout << "time: " << duration_ms << "ms\n";

    return result;
}
```

For my data that's somewhere around 800 milliseconds.

---

So lets run it under the Visual Studio profiler (Debug->Performance Profiler->CPU Usage).

[image: initial profiling run]

This just tells us that we're spending a lot of time in `memcpy` and the `pack` functions. If we expand the looooong tree of calls we get to the `stringify` function, and can look at what's actually taking the time.

If we click "Open Details..." on the main profiling page, and "Expand Hot Path", we get the following:

[image: profiling details]

This shows the sequence of pack calls taking all the time. If we click on each function call, we can see the source code in the bottom window, with a breakdown of the percentages taken by each line of code (bearing in mind that it's an optimized release build). For example, the `stringify` function is shown above.

We can see that there are a couple of `pack` functions that take longer than the rest:

- `node_msgpack::pack (84.68%)`: 17.91% of the execution time is in calling `dest.push_back(fixmap_t(n));`. If we expand it, we see that the time is almost all spent in the `std::copy` in `msgpack_byte::container::check_expand()`.
- `node_msgpack::pack (62.96%)`: 19.33% of the time is spent in `msgpack::pack` for strings... specifically in `msgpack_byte::container::check_expand()`.
- `node_msgpack::pack (41.88%)`: 36% of the time is spent in `dest.shrink_to_fit()` (which uses `memcpy`).
- `node_msgpack::pack (18.65%)`: spends all its time in `container::check_expand()` again.

So... it looks like we're spending a lot of time expanding the container (and hence copying elements after reallocation). Then we call `shrink_to_fit()` and shrink the container (and copy all the elements again)!

---

So let's not do that!

I decided to delete all the calls to `shrink_to_fit()`. I also figure that we can let `push_back` expand the container when it needs to, so I deleted the `initial` arguments and the calls to `check_resize()`.

Now stringify takes around 100 milliseconds. Much better.

---

If we profile it again, we get:

[image: second profiling run]

So we can see that ~20% of the program execution time (which is half of entire time spent in `stringify`) is spent in `node_msgpack::is_int`:

```
bool is_int(Env& env, Value& num) {
    return env.Global().Get("Number").ToObject().Get("isInteger").As<Function>().Call({ num }).ToBoolean().Value();
}
```

This doesn't look like a fast function. (Looking stuff up by string, manual type casting and function composition?) I have no idea if there's a quicker way to do the same thing with Napi. It's being called from:

```
    case napi_number: {
        if (is_int(env, src)) {
            int64_t num = src.ToNumber().Int64Value();
            if (num >= 0) {
                msgpack::pack_uint(num, dest);
            }
            else {
                msgpack::pack_int(num, dest);
            }
        }
        else {
            msgpack::pack(src.ToNumber().DoubleValue(), dest);
        }
        break;
    }
```

As I understand it, in [javascript all numbers are 64 bit floating point](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/issues/578). So since we're going to be unpacking them as `double`s anyway, the only advantage of this would be saving some space in the message.

If this is worthwhile, perhaps it's something that the `msgpack` library should do internally to all `double` values (or have a separate function to call with floating point values that probably represent integers).

It would almost certainly be quicker to check the value of the `double` in C++ instead of calling the javascript `isInteger` function.

For now let's just write doubles, and see what happens:

```
    case napi_number: {
        msgpack::pack(src.ToNumber().DoubleValue(), dest);
        break;
    }
```

Now stringify takes ~50 milliseconds!

That's probably good enough for now, but you could definitely take the profiling further.

---

### Review:

*`using namespace` is bad practice*:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace Napi;
```

This is a bad habit to get into, because it can result in [name collisions and other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

(It also makes it harder for someone with no knowledge of Napi (like me) to understand the code... is that `Array` class a `Napi` thing or not? I just have to guess.)

It's much better to type `std::` or `Napi::` where necessary.

---

*avoid unnecessary inefficiency*:

```
            const uint32_t n = input_js_arr.Length();
            vector<Value> input_vec;
            input_vec.resize(n);
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                input_vec[i] = (input_js_arr.Get(i));
            }
            pack(env, input_vec, dest);
```

We could easily write the length and then iterate through the values directly here (as we do with a map), instead of copying to a temporary vector. Then we'd only need a single `pack` function.

---

*function signature*:

```
void pack(Env& env, Value& src, msgpack_byte::container& dest)
```

If we delete `is_int` then we don't use `env` anywhere else, so we can remove this argument. Also `src` can be passed by `const&`.

---

*use `std::vector`*:

The `msgpack` library is out of scope of this review, but it should almost certainly use `std::vector`, instead of rolling its own container type.

As a side-note, you might find that `2x` is too large an expansion factor for a container, and `1.1x` is too small. [`1.5x` is fairly standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100311/what-is-the-ideal-growth-rate-for-a-dynamically-allocated-array).

Comment: If OP doesn't need memory continuity (and fairly few APIs do, unless you're interfacing with C), it might be better to use `std::deque` instead of `std::vector`.  As for `is_int()`, if it _is_ needed it would be a good idea to somehow store the value of the look up. Maybe NAPI allows exporting classes? Or just store the value in a `static` variable? If you're serializing a lot of small-ish integer data this would save quite a few bytes.

Comment: @JanDorniak Data packed with msgpack on average is 1.1 times larger than the original data, so I assumed allocating this at the start might save time compared to many small heap allocations during packing (I assumed, not sure if this makes any difference in reality)